# Lua iterators error: attempt to call a number value

Tags: lua, lua-table, luajit

```
function iter2(key,max)

    if key == nil then
        return 2 , "val:" .. 2
    end

    if key >= max then
        return nil
    else 
        return key+2, "val:" .. key+2
    end

end
```

if i invoke above iterator as below, i am getting error (attempt to call a number value):

```
for k,v in iter2(1,8) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Whereas it is working fine if i am using:

```
for k,v in iter2,1,8 do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Can anyone explain what is the difference b/w both the methods of calling?

Comment: [doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff I can understand the generic for not working because it's trying to call the return of `iter2` (which isn't a function). But how is `for k, v in iter2, 1, 8 do` explainable?

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html explains it in more depth than the reference manual.

Comment: `for k, v in iter2(1,8) do` is equivalent to `for k, v in 3, "val:3" do` The generic for will try to call 3 as it expects a function as first element in the list (3) which results in an error. `for k,v in iter2, 1, 8 instead` won't cause that error because here the first element in the list is iter2, a function variable. the generic for loop will call iter2(1, 8) which returns 3, "val:3" in the first run and so on

Comment: Similar to what @Piglet is saying, the first statement calls the function while evaluating an expression to set up the iteration; the second calls the function while iterating.

Comment: thanks for quick response. Tried to invoke the function which is returning a closure as a return value and it worked using this way func(arg1,arg2).